# MySQL: Return column1 ELSE MAX(column2,column3+20)

Tags: mysql

Where values in columns are dates.

`+20` is for 20 days.

Comment: When column1 is NULL, THEN MAX(column2,column3+20)

Comment: Fix your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: Sorry. Yes, Coeur, it's days.

Answer (score 0):

```
select if(column1,column1,greatest(column2,column3+20))
```

column1 is considered as boolean

Answer (score 0):

Returning the first non-null value in this way can be performed with the `COALESCE` operator. I believe that your problem can be solved as follows:

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1, MAX(column2, column3 + 20));
```